# "'int' object is not iterable" when trying to use glShaderSource()?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am experimenting with OpenGL(PyOpenGL) 3.3 and in Python 3.9:

```py
vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, open("assets\\vertexSrc.glsl", "r").read(), None)   << ERROR HERE
glCompileShader(vertexShader)
```

Got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\OpenGL\Python\Exploring\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, vertex_src, None)  # Defining the vertex shader source
  File "src/latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 299, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 161, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculator.c_call
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 128, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculatorElement.c_call
  File "src/wrapper.pyx", line 122, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.PyArgCalculatorElement.c_call
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\converters.py", line 305, in stringArray
    value = [as_8_bit(x) for x in arg]
TypeError: ("'int' object is not iterable", <bound method StringLengths.stringArray of <OpenGL.converters.StringLengths object at 0x0000015525B19430>>)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was trying to define the shader source, but then got that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open("assets\\vertexSrc.glsl", "r").read()` returns a python string. To create the shader from a python string you have to use overload for the python objects. See the PyOpenGL signatures of [`glShaderSource`](https://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glShaderSource.html):

> ```
> glShaderSource( GLuint ( shader ) , GLsizei ( count ) , const GLchar **( string ) , const GLint *( length ) )-> void
> glShaderSource( shaderObj , string )
> ```

Change:

<s>`glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, open("assets\\vertexSrc.glsl", "r").read(), None)`</s>

```py
glShaderSource(vertexShader, open("assets\\vertexSrc.glsl", "r").read())
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass the shader source code as a list of strings.

```
vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

# Read the shader source code from the file
with open("assets\\vertexSrc.glsl", "r") as shader_file:
    vertex_src = shader_file.read()

# Convert the source code into a list of strings (lines)
vertex_src_lines = vertex_src.split('\n')

# Pass the list of strings to glShaderSource
glShaderSource(vertexShader, len(vertex_src_lines), vertex_src_lines, None)

glCompileShader(vertexShader)
```

Comment: This does not work as `vertex_src_lines`  is not of type `const GLchar **( string )`, but a list of strings.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no need to pass the shader line-by-line. Even if an array would be necessary (which it isn't), packing the whole string in an array with a single element would be better than splitting it.